# Camel + JMX + LDAP authentication with org.apache.camel.jmx.createRmiConnector

Tags: apache-camel, jmx, jaas

all.

Have been trying to get remoted JMX with JAAS authentication to work usin Camel version 2.10.3 + Java 6.

The app uses Java DSL and is "hand wired", and runs with system properties:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true 
-Djmx.remote.x.login.config=StagingJmxAuthConfig 
-Dorg.apache.camel.jmx.usePlatformMBeanServer=true 
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./src/main/resources/conf/ldap-auth.config 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dorg.apache.camel.jmx.createRmiConnector=true
-Dorg.apache.camel.jmx.rmiConnector.registryPort=9140
```

However, for all intents and purposes it seems that I might as well be running with authentication/authorization switched off.

Debugging into the JRE's JMX and JAAS classes (and Camel as well), note the following:

In the class `org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent`:

```
cs = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, null, server);
```

This in turn later creates an instance of `javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl` with an empty Map for the `env` constructor argument.

Now, I wonder if there's something that's just escaping me -- when a request later comes to the the connector, and the `javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl` does a `doNewClient()`, it can't possibly trigger any JAAS activity?

Line 197-208 of RMIServerImpl - remember Camel sets "env" to `null`, which is translated to empty map:

```
JMXAuthenticator authenticator =
    (JMXAuthenticator) env.get(JMXConnectorServer.AUTHENTICATOR);
if (authenticator == null) {
    /*
     * Create the JAAS-based authenticator only if authentication
     * has been enabled
     */
    if (env.get("jmx.remote.x.password.file") != null ||
    env.get("jmx.remote.x.login.config") != null) {
    authenticator = new JMXPluggableAuthenticator(env);
    }
}
```

Am I correct in assuming that to get remoted, JAAS authenticated JMX to work one must hand code the JMX RMI connector setup?

Shouldn't Camel have provided an environment to get JAAS to work? Doesn't even seem to touch the JAAS config file...

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

Setting the following system properties on the VM did the trick:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9410
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
-Djmx.remote.x.login.config=StagingJmxAuthConfig
-Dorg.apache.camel.jmx.usePlatformMBeanServer=true
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./src/main/resources/conf/ldap-auth.config
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dorg.apache.camel.jmx.createRmiConnector=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.login.config=StagingJmxAuthConfig
```

For us, using a secured LDAP, the following is the login config:

```
StagingJmxAuthConfig {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.LdapLoginModule REQUIRED
   java.naming.security.authentication="simple"
   java.naming.security.principal="cn=Directory Manager"
   java.naming.security.credentials="PASSWORD"
   userProvider="ldap://LDAPHOST:389/BASEDN"
   userFilter="(&(uid={USERNAME})(appRole=SOME_VALUE))"
   authzIdentity=monitorRole
   debug=true
   useSSL=false;
   };
```

Now I'm able to connect using jmxterm:

```
java -jar jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar -l service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://THEHOST:9410/jmxrmi -u LDAPUSER -p LDAPPASS
```

Note that the JNDI RMI name is missing the "/camel" postfix -- this is the only difference, it seems.

HOORAY!

Comment: In essence:
 
- Use Java6 authenticated JMX remoting
- Set org.apache.camel.jmx.createRmiConnector=false
- Set org.apache.camel.jmx.usePlatformMBeanServer=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence:

- Use Java6 authenticated [JMX remoting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html)
- Set org.apache.camel.jmx.createRmiConnector=false
- Set org.apache.camel.jmx.usePlatformMBeanServer=true

The example above also shows how to connect to a search protected LDAP, which is actually isolated as the application in question uses a different LDAP for JNDI lookup for JMS.